# Отличие кортежей от списков

Tags: python

В чём отличие кортежей от списков в python? Они очень похожи. Почему бы всегда не использовать списки?

Comment: Tuple (кортёж)- это неизменяемый и более быстрый аналог списка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Список - аналог массивов в других языках программирования. И он изменяем, в отличии от кортежа.
Кортеж нельзя отсортировать, однако можно преобразовать в список и отсортировать уже его.
Кортеж объявляется круглыми скобками
tuple = ( 1, 2, 3 )
Список же квадратными
list = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

Comment: Ещё кортеж хешируется (может быть ключом хеша), а список - нет (не может быть ключом хеша).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy не все кортежи хешируемы, а только кортежи, содержащие хешируемые данные.

Answer (score 3):

> Помимо неизменности кортежей, существует также семантическое различие,
> которое должно служить руководством для их использования. Кортежи
> представляют собой разнородные структуры данных (т.е. Их записи имеют
> разные значения), а списки - однородные последовательности. Кортежи
> имеют структуру, списки имеют порядок.
>
> Использование этого различия делает код более явным и понятным.

[В чем разница между списками и кортежами?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/626759)

Comment: В Питоне допустим такой список  ['s', 'p', ['isok'], 2]

Comment: Полностью не согласен. Я использую кортежи везде где возможно. И лишь когда мне нужно менять контейнер, заменяют кортеж на список. Кортеж на миллион однотипных элементов - норма в моей программе.